# To find the coset of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$W = \{(x,y) : 2x+3y = 0\}$ is a subspace of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2(\mathbb{R})$.

I have to find the coset of the subspace $W$ generated by $a = (1,1)$.

This problem is totally new to me. I know the definition of coset,
Coset $\frac{V}{ W}$ is defined as elements of the form $v+W$ where $v$ is in $V$.
How to use this to find the coset of given subspace? Any hint will be appreciated.
Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We can show more generally that the coset $v+W$ of an arbitrary $v=(a,b)$ coincides with $U_v:=\{(x,y) : 2x+3y=2a+3b\}$.

Geometrically it's because the line $U_v$ is parallel to $W$, and contains $v$.